# "<<<<<<< HEAD " on the templates

Tags: git, conflict

I'm new to git. A lot of our templates have this:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            $data = unserialize( $ustate["data"] );
=======
            $data = unserialize( $ustate["data"] );
>>>>>>> 8a9dd1a09a60f2d508c8cbff60a2601a2d5beef0
```

But there is no changes to commit. When I do git status, it is just clean, nothing to commit, merge, pull, push. How can I remove these in the template?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Someone didn't do a merge properly.  You need to remove them by hand.  Check `git blame` to find the merge commit that broke it.

Comment: Yes find the person who this merge and punch them in the head repeatedly. It's good practice to do a build and test before you commit a manual merge.

Comment: FWIW, the conflict may be due to a change in whitespace, which isn't necessarily obvious when looking at the diff.  And the others are right, someone didn't resolve it correctly and left the conflict markers intact. :-(

Comment: There were a lot of uncommitted changes on one of our repo, so I checkout everything then pulled from the main repo. I guess i messed it all up and dug my own grave :D. . thanks for the reply guys :)

Answer (score 0):

These artifacts are the tags that are added when there is a conflict in the merge, and show the differences between one version and the other when doing a merge.

Now they have been pushed you will have to resolve them manually I think, although you can try doing a `git mergetool <path to file>`

This shows that HEAD had one version and commit 8a9dd1a09a60f2d508c8cbff60a2601a2d5beef0 had some other version.  However they seem to be identical so you might want to check how your line endings are handled

Comment: Thanks, i understand now. Is there any way i could resolve it all at once, we have like 50 files with that and i don't want to do it manually (T.T)

Comment: If you're sure that all conflict markers left in your files are these duplicate ones, you can use a crude shell script like this one:

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0SqbPca6

and run it with
for file in *.myextension; do ./scriptfile.sh $file; done

Answer (score 0):

yeah, I got those too. I can't remember but it seems the new update to the github app has a default setting that messes things up: tools>options> use rebase for pulls.  if that is on, uncheck it.  Then try to refresh it.  That eventually fixed it for me.

ps, I doubt "somebody messed up the merge" as they say.  I was the ONLY person working with my repositories.  I think it's a bug of some sort. (well, I guess it IS messed up, but it's probably the apps fault.  if you're not using the app, just ignore this post.)